# Use different audio profile for headphones and speakers

Tags: sound

My laptop internal speakers have a sub-woofer so I use a 2.1 profile for it. But it automatically changes to stereo when I plug in my headphones and it stays that way when I unplug them. Is there a way to treat them as different devices so they use the right profile when they are in use?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an equalizer.

#### Step 1:

Open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

#### Step 2:

Open it and put a stereo, subwoofer, etc. setting on it. (Note: Whenever you adjust one or more of the bars in there, always press 'Apply Changes') When you're done with a setting, press 'Save Preset', type the name you want, then press Enter. You can make as many as you want.

Comment: I already use pulseaudio equalizer, but I know how to change those settings. It still doesn't switch to those settings when I change the device